# Creating a welcome message in discord.js and bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async newMember => { is creating errors

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a welcome message for a discord bot, I did what guides etc said but I get the error "bot is not defined" talking about the `bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async newMember => {` part, this is using discord.js V12

My full code is:

````
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  
    message.delete()

  
// This is the needed event to use the welcome!
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async newMember => {
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: Make Sure To Use async and rename bot to client or whatever name you have for your bot events!
    const welcomeChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'imperial')
    welcomeChannel.send('Welcome User')

})
};```
````

Comment: Your `bot` is named `client`...

Comment: ah perfect thanks, stupid error on my end but at least it was a simple fix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined you Bot as Client. So you have to do `client.on`

````
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  
    message.delete()

  
// This is the needed event to use the welcome!
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async newMember => {
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: Make Sure To Use async and rename bot to client or whatever name you have for your bot events!
    const welcomeChannel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'imperial')
    welcomeChannel.send('Welcome User')

})
};```
````